# rollback transaction if commit returns error

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

**For these steps:**
 1. Start Transaction by App.router.transaction()
 2. Add Post-1 & Post-2 to transaction
 3. Delete Post-1
 4. Delete Post-2
 5. transaction.commit()

**How to handle following:**
 1. Delete record from view, After its deleted from server.
 2. If Commit fails, Rollback transaction. So Records is visible again in View.
 3. How to show deleted records in view, as After Local delete it gets removed from collection.

Answer (score 0):

1. The record will be removed from the collection by ember-data once the ajax transaction successfully commits.
2. If commit fails, it will not be removed from the collection by ember-data.  The ajax.success callback calls a function that removes the records from the collection. There appears to be no error handler.
3. The items will be deleted from the collection once the commit succeeds. If you want to show the records as deleted you may want to set a deleted flag property on the posts and then update them instead of delete them. This is something I ran into as well.